# URL scheme not registed while debugging

Tags: swift, macos

For a Mac OSX application I am developing, I want to use an URL scheme, so I set up the scheme like this:

```
NSAppleEventManager.shared().setEventHandler(
    self,
    andSelector: #selector(handleUrlEvent(_:with:)),
    forEventClass: AEEventClass(kInternetEventClass),
    andEventID: AEEventID(kAEGetURL))
```

And I have a handler registered like this:

```
@objc
func handleUrlEvent(_ event: NSAppleEventDescriptor, with replyEvent: NSAppleEventDescriptor) {
    log.verbose("handleUrlEvent")
}
```

My URL scheme is registered in my Info.plist

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Viewer</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>Look for photo</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>gisync</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

The problem is, when I run my application using Xcode, the URL scheme is not registered and the application does not get the events I need.

When I archive and start my application from there, the scheme **IS** registered and the application gets the notifications. So then it works correctly, but I lose debugging capabilities.

**EDIT**: The release build does work somehow, so this seems to be different for release and debug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try explicitly registering the app with the Launch Services:
[LSRegisterURL](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreservices/1446350-lsregisterurl)

> This function adds the designated application and its document and URL claims (if any) to the Launch Services database, making the application a candidate for document and URL binding.

I’d do it in the `applicationDidFinishLaunching` and use conditional compilation to only do this in the DEBUG version.

Also version number of an app bundle has effect:
[Preferred Application for a URL](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/LaunchServicesConcepts/LSCConcepts/LSCConcepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000999-CH202-SW24)

> If two or more versions of the same application have been found, give preference to the one with the latest version number.

Comment: Setting the version number and cleaning and rebuilding didn't work. After an Xcode restart however, it did work... Thanks!